# How do I do this Boolean condition?

Tags: android-studio

```
    val username = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.username)
    val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.password)
    val login_status = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.login_status)
    val login = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login_button)

    login.setOnClickListener {

        if (username.text.isEmpty())
            username.setError("Please enter your username")

        if(password.text.isEmpty())
            password.setError("Please enter your password")

        if (!username.text.isEmpty() && !password.text.isEmpty()) {

            var correct_name = "Alibaba"
            var correct_password = "baba0123"

                if (username.text.equals(correct_name) && password.text.equals(correct_password))
                    login_status.text = String.format("Correct username and password.Welcome Alibaba!")
    }


}
```

}}

Hi guys, I'm really struggling with the if statement plus the boolean condition on how to make the username and password as the thing I want such as username is "Alibaba" and password is "baba0123".It keeps showing me the other way around when I try to run on my AVD manager,like I type the correct username and password , but it keeps showing nothing on  my screen. Helppppppp

Comment: Welcome to SO. The property `text` on `EditText` widgets is not a `String` but an `Editable` which is... Android nonsense. So you need to convert it to a `String` to be able to perform what you're trying to do. You can do so by using the convenience `toString()` method. So add `xxx.text.toString().isEmpty()`. On that note, I suggest you use `isBlank()` instead of `isEmpty()` since the former will return true if the string contains *only spaces* as well (so for `"     "` isBlank() = false, but isEmpty() = true.)

Answer (score 0):

you are missing toString() with text fields
and try this customise code
with trim() and ignorecase

you should have to post screenshot so we have better understanding

```
login.setOnClickListener {
    if (username.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        username.setError("Please enter your username")
        return
    }
    if(password.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        password.setError("Please enter your password")
        return
    }
    var correct_name = "Alibaba"
    var correct_password = "baba0123"
    if(username.text.toString().trim().equals(correct_name, ignoreCase = true) && password.text.toString().trim().equals(correct_password))
        login_status.text = String.format("Correct username and password.Welcome Alibaba!")
}
```